# Create an array for several UIViewControllers

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsarray

So I want to create an array that would contain my App's `UNViewControllers`. I'm using a navigationcontroller to switch between views. What my overall aim is to use this Array so that I can load the views using this array. My only problem is I don't have an idea how I would utilise this function. Do I need to create the array in my Projects AppDelegate file so I can apply the Array to all my sub ViewControllers? Any advice would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: UINavigationController has a property of array of UIViewControllers. I don't think you have to prepare an array by yourself. Initialize UIViewControllers when you need and push them to the navigation controller. I would do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a navigation controller right?  So you don't need an array of viewcontrollers, the navigation controller will handle it.  Just give each view controller an identifier in interface builder (storyboard) and then use:

```
MyViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVCIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Oh yeh I've done that. I thought I hadn't explained it properly :/. I've created a shake gesture and I want it to call up a random page when you use the shake function, I assumed I'd need a array because I'd be calling up a random integer. Does that make sense?